# Rails rake tasks aborting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am having trouble running any rake task for my Rails application, and no matter what task I run (rake db:migrate, rake db:reset, etc), I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pages: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
```

I continue getting this error - no matter what rake task I run, and also when I try to run the server:

```
rails s
```

gets the following error

```
Exiting
/Users/terencedevine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pages: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Everything I find online suggests using `rake db:reset` but that returns the same error.

One of my more recent migrations I ran was a `XXXX_create_pages.rb` which has the following code:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, unique: true
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Backtrace please! :)

Comment: Could you give a little more info on `Backtrace` please?

Comment: Backtrace is (or rather should be) displayed directly under the error message and contains information necessary to find what is causing the exception.

Comment: It means table 'pages' does not exists. Please list at lease 5 migrations (2 before pages migration and 2 aftre) with their full names.

Comment: I have no more migrations after create_pages... the last 5 migrations were added as a screenshot to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you actually execute your migrations.

Try `rake db:migrate` then try to run your server or console again.

Comment: all rake tasks get aborted, when I run `rake db:migrate` I get: `rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pages: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"` with a bunch more output below.

Comment: Try `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` then `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate` and that should work.

Comment: all rake tasks get aborted, when I run `rake db:create` it either says the sqlite3 files are created, or creates them (if I remove them). When I then run `rake db:migrate` I get the same error as above: `rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pages: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pages: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
```

From the error message, it's obvious that the `pages` table does not exist in your database right now. It got deleted somehow even if you did not delete it knowingly.

So, you should create the `pages` table again by running the corresponding migration:

`rake db:migrate`

In case your schema version exceeded to migration `XXXX_create_pages.rb` then rename you migration with greatest timestamp.

Eg.

Your page migration is

```
20151130203912_create_pages.rb
```

If your current schema version is

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20151211175046)
```

Then `pages` migration must be `20151230203912_create_pages.rb`

I hope it would be helpful.